# Characterize the set of complex $z$ such that $a + \frac{a+8b}{a^2 + b^2} = 2$ and $b + \frac{8a-b}{a^2 + b^2} = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, contest-math

> Characterize the set of  $z = a + bi$ such that
> $$a + \frac{a+8b}{a^2 + b^2} = 2\\
> b + \frac{8a-b}{a^2 + b^2} = 0$$
> *Source: Art of Problem Solving*

I've made progress but been unable to complete this problem correctly.  Can you help me figure out my mistake or take a better approach?

In general, the approach I've taken has proven difficult, because the manipulations grow too complex to do correctly (even after many rounds of checking), but I can find no approach that avoids them.

Additionally: I normally try to have some *qualitative* description of what the equations tell me or where I'm going, but am unable to do so here.  The only way I saw to proceed here was to replace $a$ and $b$ with their $z, \bar z$ extractions, so that everything is in the same single variable $z$.  Is there an insight, a picture, a realization relevant here that can replace blind manipulations?

---

My work so far:
Let $w = \frac {1 + 8i}{z}, v = \frac {1 - 8i}{z}$.  Then since $a = \frac{z + \bar z }{2}, b= \frac{z - \bar z}{2i}$, we have $$a + \frac{a+8b}{a^2 + b^2} = 2 \\
z + \bar z + \frac{z + \bar z - 8i(z - \bar z)}{z \bar z} = 4\\
z + \bar z + w + \bar w = 4$$ and $$b + \frac{8a-b}{a^2 + b^2} = 0\\
-i(z - \bar z) + \frac{8(z + \bar z) + i(z - \bar z) }{z \bar z} = 0 \\
% -i[z - \bar z + \frac{-8zi - 8 \bar z i - z + \bar z}{z \bar z}] = 0 \\
% z - \bar z + \frac{\bar z -  8 \bar z i  - (z + 8zi)}{z \bar z} = 0 \\
z - \bar z + \frac {1 - 8i}{z} - \frac {1 + 8i}{\bar z}= 0\\
z - \bar z + v - \bar v= 0$$ so $$2z + w + v + \bar w - \bar v = 4\\
z + \frac 1 z = 2 \\
z^2 - 2z + 1 = 0\\
(z-1)(z - 1) = 0 \\
z = 1.$$

However, that does not meet the original equations.

---

What is my error? Is there a better approach?

---

### Update

With help from "SwagBeastSKJ", this should be: $$2z + w + v + \bar w - \bar v = 4\\
z + \frac 1 z = 2 - 4i\\
z^2 + (-2 + 4i)z + 1 = 0
$$

I could then use the quadratic formula... but something tells me I'm missing the boat.  There *must* be an elegant approach, an insight, that I'm missing.

Comment: Why not discuss this at *Art of Problem Solving* ??

Comment: How did you go from $2z + w + v + \bar{w} - \bar{v}$ to $z + \frac{1}{z}$

Comment: @SwagBeastSKJJ Thank you.  I thought $w + v = \frac 2 z, \bar w - \bar v = 0$.  Then divide both sides by 2.  But I see  $\bar w - \bar v = -8i$.  Let me work this...

Comment: I think you have $\bar{w} - \bar{v}$ wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $z = a + bi$

$$ a + \frac{a + 8b}{a^2 + b^2} = 2 $$
$$ b + \frac{8a - b}{a^2 + b^2} = 0$$

Multiplying second equation by $i^3$ we get

$$-bi + \frac{-8ai + bi}{a^2 + b^2} = 0$$

Adding with our first equation gives us

$$ a - bi + \frac{a - 8ai + 8b + bi}{a^2 + b^2} = 2$$

$$ \implies \bar{z} + \frac{z - 8zi}{z\bar{z}} = 2$$

$$ \implies \bar{z} + \frac{1-8i}{\bar{z}} = 2$$

Which is a quadratic equation with complex roots in $\bar{z}$ and can be easily solved.

This gives us solutions $\bar{z} = -1 - 2i$ and $\bar{z} = 3 + 2i$ which means $z = -1 + 2i$ and $z = 3 - 2i$, and checking the solutions we find this is indeed the solution to the given equation.